# Build server Unity3d + iOS to ipa files

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, testflight, ipa, fastlane

Did anyone configure Unity3d build server with iOS building to ipa files (and maybe sending to TestFlight/diawi)? If so, could you share your configuration. 
Does Unity Cloud support iOS building to ipa files? Does it support fastlane?

Answer (score 1):

We use our own machine running Jenkins as build server. When Unity finished building Xcode project, we copy fastlane config(Fastfile and any other stuff) into it then trigger fastlane. The fastlane actions we used are cocapods(Install CocoaPods), sigh(Provision), gym(Build) and deliver(Upload to iTunes Connect).

Comment: thank you for the answer! Xcode projects built by Unity doesn't have any pods, did you add custom pods somehow?

Comment: We use Firebase Unity Plugin, it somehow adds pods to the built Unity Xcode project and requires CocoaPods to be executed on it.